# Oracle 10g Export data to CSV

Tags: oracle10g, export-to-csv

It there an easy way of exporting all tables in an Oracle 10g database to individual CSV files?  I won't be able to use a third-party tool as I won't be able to use those tools that need to connect to the Oracle server itself in order to migrate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider write a PL/SQL script that exports all your data from within Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You said, "I won't be able to use those tools that need to connect to the Oracle server itself in order to migrate it."

I"m assuming you mean the file copy from the server to workstation, but SQL developer uses connections to extract the data and generates the csv files locally.

Use SQL Developer:

- access the schema to export
- go tables list
- select upper most table in list.
- Holding shift select bottom most table in display
- right click on any table select export from popup
- Uncheck export DDL
- change format under export data to csv
- under save as select multiple files
- browse to destination
- next
- next
- finish

Screenshot from after right click on any table select export from popup.

[image]